# extract hidden email from webpage using requests and regular expression

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to find the email in this webpage:
https://reachuae.com/livesearch/brand-detail/3910/A-ALICO-LTD-Sharjah

I created this code but no email found:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://reachuae.com/livesearch/brand-detail/3910/A-ALICO-LTD-Sharjah'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
page_text = r.text
email = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b',page_text)
print(email)
```

return empty list

Comment: I didn't find any email on this page.

Comment: I used a software called Advanced Email Extractor and it scraped the email ! this is why I thought that there was an email there

Comment: You didn't know how did Advanced Email Extractor work,if you couldn't find the "hidden" email manually, that's very hard to scrape the email you want.

Comment: I used the code to try this webpage but return empty list too, any thoughts ? : https://aiwa.ae/company/arad-building-material-trading

Comment: I don't know how to get it by scraper,but this page seems use `Javascript` to load the email dynamically.You could see it in the `Developer Tools -> Network`And you will see a js file called `email-decode.min.js`.I think that's how does this page generate email.

Comment: Is it possible to call the js function locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email is not found in the URL which you have mentioned in the question, but when you click the "(Click here to send enquiry)" another URL is generating at the bottom of page. That URL is containing the mail id. Using the below python code you can extract that Mail id

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Mail_url = 'https://reachuae.com/livesearch/brand-detail/3910/A-ALICO-LTD-Sharjah'

def mailExtractor():
    mail = Mail_url.split('/')
    innumber = mail[-2]
    Actual_url = 'https://reachuae.com/includes/contact_company.php?id={}&KeepThis=true&'.format(innumber)
    getr = requests.get(Actual_url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"})
    sour = html.fromstring(getr.content)
    emails = sour.xpath('//input[@name="mail"]//@value')
    for mail in emails:
        print(mail)

mailExtractor()
```

Comment: it worked, thanks, we can apply the same to this page : https://aiwa.ae/keyword/building-materials-suppliers ?

Comment: It is very simple to extract the data from aiwa.ae

Comment: Try to analyse the website and its structure and write some code to extract the data. same logic may not work for another site. You have to think, Do your own research